# Добавление элементов в разметку

Tags: javascript

Как с помощью JS динамически добавлять новые контроллы (input, div и тд) ?
Пробую так :

```
 function AddItem()
 {
   var element = document.getElementById("add_scill").innerHTML = '<span>111</span>';
 }
```

И новый блок спан действительно добавляется в разметку, но только 1 раз а как сделать что бы добавлялся каждый раз при вызове функции ? И связанный вопрос - что, если добавляется не просто '...' а сложные элементы, формы и тд - описывать их в строку не очень удобно, может есть более продвинутый способ ?

Comment: Проверьте мой ответ, такое поведение хотите?

Comment: @Klimenkomud да. только что если я захочу добавить 2 инпута или один див с 2 инпутами и еще елементами ?

Comment: Тогда можно передавать в функцию название создаваемого элемента, и `id` блока, в котором нужно что-то создавать. Чуть позже дополню код. Я в целом понимаю, что вам нужен "швейцарский нож", поэтому, взгляните всё-таки в сторону библиотек

Comment: @Klimenkomud название создаваемого элемента - это Name <Div>?

Comment: Нет, это просто `div` или `input` или `span`. Строка.

Comment: @Klimenkomud а какие библиотеки можно использовать как швейцарский нож?) можно конечно и просто строку html разметки, но наверняка это устаревший способ.

Comment: Да, это устаревший вариант. Как правило для такого используются `template`. Не могу вам точно сказать, что именно подойдет под вашу задачу, это зависит от бизнес-логики вашего приложения. Если инпутов должно быть определённое колличество - вы вполне можете заложить их в `template`, отрендерить его и выводить по нажатию на кнопку нужные инпуты в нужных блоках. Думаю, будет лучше если вы зададите отдельный вопрос по этому поводу, потому как в контексте данного вопроса решение уже найдено.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Элемент добавляется не 1 раз, просто каждый раз вы затираете `innerHTML` новым значением.

```
function AddItem() {
var input = document.createElement('input');
  var element = document.getElementById("add_scill");
  element.appendChild(input);
 };
```

Если таким образом - каждый раз будет добавляться ещё один элемент.
P.S.
Более продвинутый способ - скорее всего заюзать каку-нибудь библиотеку.

Comment: тут нюанс возникает - если я добавляю input и введу что либо в него а потом решу создать еще один input  то то что я ввел в первый сотрется.

Comment: У Вас тут в отредактированном варианте опечатка - создаете переменную `input`, а добавляете `newInput`. :)

Comment: @Yaant Спасибо, поправил :)

Answer (score 3):

```js
function AddItem() {
  let newSpan = document.createElement('span');
  newSpan.innerText = '111';
  document.getElementById('add_scill').appendChild(newSpan);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="AddItem()" value="Add item">
<div id="add_scill"></div>
```